# How can I see that some of the arguments from my in statement did not match a row in the database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a query where I can find the status of an account based on the email. It is possible that I will get a list of email addresses where some will correspond to an account and others will not. I am trying a statement like:

```
select * from accounts where email address in 
(
'abc@example.com',
'123@example.com',
'XYZ@example.com',
)
```

This is working to show me everything where there is a match, but it's not showing me when one of those emails is not found, so if there was no account for XYZ@example.com I would only get two rows. That's causing me problems when it's a long list of arguments when trying to figure out which ones did not have a match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join`:

```
select v.email, . . .
from (values ('abc@example.com'), ('123@example.com'), ('XYZ@example.com')
     ) v(email) left join
     accounts a
     on a.email = v.email;
```

If you just want the ones without a match, then add `where a.email is null`.